# Spring batch unit testing job with external input and db output

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

If I understand it correctly normal way of spring batch testing is to basically run my application and let `JobLauncherTestUtils` run my normal jobs. However my application reads input from external service and writes it to my database. I don't want my tests to write to my production database and I'd like to specify test input to be read rather from the files I'd provide than from external service.

Can anyone direct me to some example how I could do it? I'd like to feed a job with a file then when job has finished check in the database that what I expect is there. I guess I could specify h2 db in application-test.properties but I have no clue about the input.

Docs from https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing don't really cover it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you reading input files from disk?  If so you can edit the input file source directory only for tests to be within the src/test/resources/input_dir/your_test_file.xml for example.

If the input file directory is configured with properties, you could create properties file only for tests with something like classpath:input_dir/your_test_file.xml (which would be in your project as src/test/resources/input_dir/your_test_file.xml).

If the input file directory is configured within execution context you can provide that in the jobExecutionContext parameter of JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep

Comment: I read external service via http, it's just external server exposing data.